# Selecting appended link buttons with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am appending a td with two link buttons inside the td and a variable named counter, on the click of the link buttons i want the counter variable to be
incremented or decremented but I cant figure out how to select the appended link buttons with jQuery. Below is my code:-

```
var quantity = 1;

$("#order-table table").append('
<tr>
<td><button class="btn btn-link js-increment">+</button>' + quantity + 
'<button class="btn btn-link">-</button></td>
</tr>')
```

here is my function trying to increment the variable

```
$(".js-increment").click(function () {
quantity++;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add new elements to the DOM, you need to attach an event listener to an element that is already in the DOM... like `body` or your `table`.

Here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nkqbw2jz/) with the code you provided and some small changes.

```
var quantity = 1;

$("#order-table table").append('<tr><td><button class = "btn btn-link btn-plus"> + </button><span class="value">' + quantity + '</span><button class = "btn btn-link btn-minus"> - </button></td></tr>');

$('body').on('click', '.btn-plus', function() {
    quantity++;
  $(this).next('.value').text(quantity);
});

$('body').on('click', '.btn-minus', function() {
    quantity--;
  $(this).prev('.value').text(quantity);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your quantity with a `span` like this. Also, add different classes to the buttons:

```
$("#order-table table").append('
<tr>
    <td>
      <button class="btn btn-link btn-increment">+</button>
      <span>' + quantity + '</span>
      <button class="btn btn-link btn-decrement">-</button>
   </td>
</tr>')
```

Add the following click events inside your document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").on('click', '#order-table table .btn-increment', function(){
      $quantity = $(this).closest("td").find("span");
      $quantity.text(parseInt($quantity.text()) + 1);
  });

  $("body").on('click', '#order-table table .btn-decrement', function(){
      $quantity = $(this).closest("td").find("span");
      $quantity.text(parseInt($quantity.text()) - 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your solution is almost complete but the click event won't work because the element is not already in the DOM. You need to use something like: `$("#order-table table").on('click', '.btn-increment', function() {});` for it to work on dynamically generated elements like OP mentioned when he wrote `append`.

Comment: @vyx.ca I'm a buffoon. Updated.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to select the buttons using `$('.btn-link')`. Are you trying to select each button separately?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrERGJ?editors=1111